# jQuery scrollLeft animates to wrong position

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, scroll

I'm doing a webpage with a slideshow, with a `jQuery scrollLeft function`.
My problem is that it works on the first `.slide` then the div scrolls to a completely wrong position.
Note that I'm using the function on two different classes!

Here's a jsfiddle of my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/5xx6g7j8/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I update your jsfiddle. -> https://jsfiddle.net/5xx6g7j8/1/

```
$('#slideShow').stop().animate({
       scrollLeft: Math.abs($('#slideWrap').offset().left) + $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left 
}, 1500);
```

I think now works properly. You just had to take care about the current offset of the container before start the animation.

I hope it helps.

EDIT: I see now that I forgot an alert. Sorry

Comment: Cheers mate, that really helped!
No probs with the alert! I just copied from here.